# Windows 10 Simple PIN

Tags: login, windows-10

One login feature of Windows 10 is that it allows you to log in with a PIN instead of with your password.  This is especially useful for those of us who have complex Microsoft Account passwords but just want to discourage casual laptop use by other people in the home/office.

While the PIN defaults to be numbers only, the Windows 10 Preview builds [had a checkbox](http://mcakins.com/2015/01/26/windows-10-jtp-now-supports-extended-pin/) to turn off "Simple PIN" mode and allow the use of letters and symbols in the PIN.  In the preview builds, I used this feature.

I can't seem to find this checkbox in the Windows 10 release.  Did they move it somewhere else, or remove it entirely?

My Windows 10 testing Virtual Machine, which already had a complex PIN (with letters) set when the Preview was installed is continuing to use that PIN now that it has upgraded to the full version.  However, on my laptop which has been upgraded from Windows 8.1, I can't seem to set it.

Comment: [It was removed several builds ago.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_security/windows-10-10162-complex-pin-option-is-gone/6fd505fe-8b56-4e81-ad9b-09e263a59ccc)

Comment: Using the release build of windows 10 pro, I can still find the pin setting under "sign-in options" under "accounts" in settings

Comment: @Blaine the missing part isn't the PIN feature, it is the "complex PIN" check box on that page.

Comment: @Ramhound It's been a while. Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Feel free to self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature has now be added back to Windows 10 (not sure exactly when, but it is definitely in 1803 / build 17134).

[image: PIN screen showing complex PIN option]

Answer (score 0):

As discovered by [@Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound), the feature was [removed from build 10162](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_security/windows-10-10162-complex-pin-option-is-gone/6fd505fe-8b56-4e81-ad9b-09e263a59ccc).

> Ravinath P replied on  July 21, 2015:
>
> Hi,
>
> Complex Pin is not present in the latest Preview builds.
>
> Thank you.

Comment: The insider preview build that Ravinath P talks about is the Version 1511 Insider Preview builds.  In other words this feature was removed between build 10240 and 10586.0.  I went ahead and quoted the relevant information.